# How can I create a column family without defining any column in apache phoenix?

Tags: hbase, ddl, apache-phoenix, column-family, nosql

According to the description on phoenix website:

Following create table DDL will create two column faimiles A and B.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (MYKEY VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, A.COL1 VARCHAR,
 A.COL2 VARCHAR, B.COL3 VARCHAR)
```

But I need to create a column family without defining any column, so all columns belong to the column family will be dynamic. Except for creating a dummy column for the column family, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported.

http://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html#column_def

A column definition includes a column reference.

http://phoenix.apache.org/language/index.html#column_ref

And we can see that the column family is optional while the column name is not.

If you would like this feature to be implemented, please open a feature request ticket on https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: Thank you, Kliew. This really helps. At least, I am sure what I can do for this.